# Rotating Shift by Week

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am attempting to create an auto-rotating shift as follows:

There are 9 employees.

The shifts are:

Tuesday 12 - 2 in half an hour blocks (12, 12:30, 1:00, 1:30)
Thursday 11:30 - 2:00 in half an hour blocks (11:30, 12, 12:30, 1:00, 1:30)

The last person to work on Thursday should be the first person to work on Tuesday of the next week.

Ex.

Week One

```
           11:30-A
```

12:00-L        12:00-B
12:30-LD       12:30-D
1:00-M         1:00-H
1:30 R         1:30-K

Week Two

```
           11:30-R
```

12:00-K        12:00-A
12:30-L        12:30-B
1:00-LD        1:00-D
1:30 M         1:30-H

I am not sure how to code that. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Let's solve this problem together step by step.

First of all, create a list of employees.

The shift schedule will be placed in a rectangular table.
Get something like this

[image: Empty table]

Let's say we renumber our employees from 0 to 8 (yes, you can renumber from 1 to 9, but the formula will get a little more complicated because of this)

And now we get the number of the employee, depending on which row and which column he is on duty:

```
=MOD((COLUMN()-COLUMN($Cell_of_the_very_first_block))*8+ROW()-ROW($Cell_of_the_very_first_block),9)
```

In my example, the cell of the very first block is located at **E5**, so the formula will be:

```
=MOD((COLUMN()-COLUMN($E$5))*8+ROW()-ROW($E$5),9)
```

[image: Numbers in the table]

Look at the numbers week by week. You see? This seems to be the correct order of shifts. Now, using the OFFSET() function, let's turn these numbers into employee names:

```
=OFFSET($A$5, MOD((COLUMN()-COLUMN($E$5))*8+ROW()-ROW($E$5),9),0)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This worked amazingly! Thanks so much for the help!